# bash script Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Tags: bash, nginx

I'm trying to run this dropbox script on my nginx server , but im getting:

```
 Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

I copy pasted the script for a website, and I tried removing special characters, but im still getting the same error.

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/dropbox
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          dropbox
# Required-Start:    $network $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $syslog $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $named $time
# Should-Stop:       $named $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the dropbox daemon for debian/ubuntu
# Description:       Dropbox daemon for linux
### END INIT INFO

DROPBOX_USERS="root"
start() {
    echo "Starting dropbox..."
    for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
        start-stop-daemon -b -o -c $dbuser -S -x /home/$dbuser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
    done
}

stop() {
    echo "Stopping dropbox..."
    for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
        start-stop-daemon -o -c $dbuser -K -x /home/$dbuser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
    done
}

status() {
    for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
        dbpid=`pgrep -u $dbuser dropbox`
        if [ -z $dbpid ] ; then
            echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: not running."
        else
            echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: running."
        fi
    done
}


case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;

  stop)
    stop
    ;;

  restart|reload|force-reload)
    stop
    start
    ;;

  status)
    status
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}"
    exit 1

esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Start removing lines/chunks from the script until you no longer get the error. Best way to reduce when you don't understand the problem is through trial and error.

Comment: Just do `bash -x` to debug. A lot of unquoted variables, could cause other issues, but don't think the specific error.

Comment: Try using ${DROPBOX_USERS}

Comment: I was able to get the same error in dash with `for a in a b c ; word`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably you managed to insert windows line endings when you copy and pasted. If you have dos2unix, use it. (dos2unix scriptfile) Otherwise, there are a number of similar utilities.

Comment: So this fixed the other error now i'm getting: `/etc/init.d/dropbox: ï»¿#:` not found

Comment: @Undermine2k: That will be the pseudo-BOM which Windows likes to insert at the beginning of a UTF-8 text file, unnecessarily IMHO. Using a text editor *on the server*, delete and retype the first line (#!/bin/sh).

Comment: Use dos2unix >= 6.0.0 and it will also remove the BOM.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you have

```
/home/$dbuser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

or replacing variables.

```
/home/root/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Shouldn't it be

```
/root/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

eg

```
/$dbuser/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Are you seriously allowing dropboxes in `/root` ?

Also why a `for dbuser in DROPBOX_USERS; do` reassign? rather than

```
dbuser=$DROPBOX_USERS
```

Comment: Downvote for patronizing people who have a different perspective on `root` usage than you.